# Difference in meaning between 'the' and 'that'

Tags: meaning, definite-articles, demonstratives

I have some doubts about the meaning of 'the' and 'that' in the following two constructions:

1. **The** house over there is mine.
2. **That** house over there is mine.

Is there any difference in meaning between 'the' and 'that' here? Or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one house over there, then they are equivalent. If there are several, "that house" would go with an indication of which house, eg by pointing. "The house" assumes there is only one possibility.

Comment: Your explanation is admirably simple and clear.Yet l expect there is a more in-depth explanation regarding the common origin of  'that' and 'the'.

Comment: You could try https://www.etymonline.com for details about their origins.

Comment: _The_ is the definite article. _This_ and _that_ indicate particular objects, near and far from the speaker.

Comment: They are not interchangeable.